# how to use a double in console app?

Tags: c#, double, console-application

How do I use a double in a console app to handle decimal places I tryed changing the int to double?

```
double[] myArrai1 = new double[3];
for (double myDouble = 0; myDouble < myArrai1.Length; myDouble++ )
Console.WriteLine(myArrai1[myDouble]);
```

I get the error cant convert double type to int (obviously) but not sure how I can manage an array in c console app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double[] myArrai1 = new double[3];
for (int index = 0; index < myArrai1.Length; index ++ )
Console.WriteLine(myArrai1[index ]);
```

The index to the array needs to be an int, not a double.  I also changed the variable name to properly reflect its meaning.

The other option would be to use a foreach loop:

```
double[] myArrai1 = new double[3];
foreach(double myDouble in myArrai1)
  Console.WriteLine(myDouble);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are indexed by integers, not doubles. You can get a double from the array using the following:

```
double[] myArrai1 = new double[3];
for (int i = 0; i < myArrai1.Length; i++ )
{
    double myDouble = myArrai1[i];
    Console.WriteLine(myDouble);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a double as an array accessor.  That should always be an integral value, so:

```
for (int index = 0; index < myArrai1.Length; index++ )
Console.WriteLine(myArrai1[index]);
```

Alternatively, you could use C#'s foreach syntax, like:

```
foreach (double d in myArrai1) {
Console.WriteLine( d );
}
```